# How to set the font size or size of the Visual Studio 2015 Quick Find Dialog

Tags: visual-studio

All of a sudden the quick find dialog in Visual Studio seems to have shrunk to the point where the font size seems very small and is hard to ready.  I've tried resetting all my fonts and colors and that did not work.  There does not seem to be a specific font setting for the quick find dialog.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some stupid reason the font size in the quick find dialog seems to be related to the font size in the editor. Try to change text editor font size buy pressing Ctrl and scroll on the mouse wheel.